# Execute two and more files in Geany 1.32 in KDE Plasma 5.12.9

Tags: kubuntu, geany

I can easily run my python or fortran program in Geany 1.32. The konsole starts normally. Though when I try to start another program or run the same program again it deletes the console with the first program. I was used from Gnome, that I could run many instances of the program. Maybe it is some settings I have forget, but settings in older Geany 1.27 looks pretty much the same.
In the picture I show icon that should be black, instead it is red. After clicking it opened windows is closed. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to downgrade Geany to 1.27 which does not help, but simple workaround is just to install original Terminal. (E.g. in Discover the GNOME terminal).
https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal

And to change settings in Geany: Edit > Preferences > Tools (bar) > Terminal option command:

```
gnome-terminal -e "/bin/bash %c"
```

(originally there was:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "/bin/sh %c"
```

which launches Konsole and this did not work)